LATEX TikZ package Ubicar la figura en la página
Estoy tratando de ubicar una figura con texto en el borde de la página, estoy usando el paquete \usepackage{tikz} y sus librerías. Tengo los siguinetes problemas:

No he podido ubicar el la figura en el borde de la página.
Esa figura tiene una línea en el borde y na sé el porqué.
El texto se sale del rectángulo y si escribo un texto más extenso, se saldrá del rectángulo.

Este es el código que estoy usando:
\usepackage{shapepar}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usetikzlibrary {positioning}
\usetikzlibrary {positioning,shapes.misc}
\usetikzlibrary {backgrounds}

\begin{document}

\newgeometry{top=30mm, left=30mm, bottom=30mm, right=20mm} 
\pagecolor{white}\afterpage{\nopagecolor}

\begin{tikzpicture}
 \node [fill=white] at (0,0) {Hello world};
 \scoped [on background layer]
 \filldraw [gray] (0,4) rectangle (8,8);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}


Jugando con los números, no he podido:

Gracias.
